# Pandas dataframe into a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I am trying too read a csv file and convert it into a 2d array according to the following principle:
[ [12, 22] ,[11,21] ] etc.
I used the following code

```
import pandas as pd
fields = ['month', '8.2']
data = pd.read_csv('demand_with_station_id.csv',   index_col=1 ,usecols = fields)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
supralist = []
for indx, val in df.iterrows():
    lst = [val[indx]['month'], val[indx]['8.2']]
    supralist.append(lst)
print(supralist)
```

It results in an error.
I want not to read the first four rows into the list, how do I do that?
The csv file is a bit non-standard and it looks like this:
[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BzDY.png)

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 'Friday'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use values.tolist() on the columns which you want to be list of list.

you don't need to loop and create the list.

```
data_list=df[['month', '8.2']].values.tolist()
```

to exclude the first 4 records from the list you can now remove it form data_list

```
data_list=data_list[4:]
```